# distribute array values in multiple select box

Tags: php, loops, for-loop, foreach

I have an array as follows

```
$myArray = array('a','b','c','d');
```

I need to distribute some values of them saved already in database into different number of select boxes let's say 4 list boxes so these saved values will appear **selected** in the first list boxes and the remaining ones will be default and let's say saved values are **a and c**

so based on that the output should have 4 list boxes starting with a (Selected) and second list box c (Selected) and the other 2 list boxes should be remained default something like that

```
<select id="id" name="id" class="form-control">
    <option value="">No selection</option>
    <option value="a" selected>a</option>
    <option value="b">b</option>
    <option value="c">c</option>
    <option value="d">d</option>
</select>

<select id="id" name="id" class="form-control">
    <option value="">No selection</option>
    <option value="a">a</option>
    <option value="b">b</option>
    <option value="c" selected>c</option>
    <option value="d">d</option>
</select>

<select id="id" name="id" class="form-control">
    <option value="" selected>No selection</option>
    <option value="a">a</option>
    <option value="b">b</option>
    <option value="c">c</option>
    <option value="d">d</option>
</select>

<select id="id" name="id" class="form-control">
    <option value="" selected>No selection</option>
    <option value="a">a</option>
    <option value="b">b</option>
    <option value="c">c</option>
    <option value="d">d</option>
</select>
```

**Edit**
Here is my code where i loop to produce either 7 or 9 list boxes according to the passed value and inside i loop on `$municipals` to show all municipals and a municipal exists inside an array of the saved values in DB i need to show it in the first select box and so on

```
                    <?php if(!empty($municipal_number->meta_value)):
                        $ids = array();

                        foreach($municipal_ids as $municipal_id) {
                            $ids[] = $municipal_id->meta_value;
                        }

                    if($municipal_number->meta_value == 7):  
                        for ($x = 1; $x <= 7; $x++): ?>
                            <div class="col-lg-3">
                                <label>Select Municipal</label>

                                <select id="municipal_id_<?php echo $x; ?>" name="municipal_id[]" class="municipal_id form-control">
                                    <option value="0" selected>No Municipal</option>

                                    <?php foreach($municipals as $municipal): ?>
                                        <?php if(in_array($municipal->id, $ids)): ?>
                                            <option selected value="<?php echo $municipal->id; ?>"><?php echo $municipal->first_name.' '.$municipal->last_name; ?></option>
                                        <?php else: ?>
                                            <option value="<?php echo $municipal->id; ?>"><?php echo $municipal->first_name.' '.$municipal->last_name; ?></option>
                                        <?php endif; ?>
                                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        <?php endfor;
                    elseif($municipal_number->meta_value == 9):
                        for ($x = 1; $x <= 9; $x++): ?>
                            <div class="col-lg-3">
                                <label>Select Municipal</label>

                                <select id="municipal_id_<?php echo $x; ?>" name="municipal_id[]" class="municipal_id form-control">
                                    <option value="0" selected>No Municipal</option>

                                    <?php foreach($municipals as $municipal): ?>
                                        <?php if(in_array($municipal->id, $ids)): ?>
                                            <option value="<?php echo $municipal->id; ?>"><?php echo $municipal->first_name.' '.$municipal->last_name; ?></option>
                                        <?php else: ?>
                                            <option value="<?php echo $municipal->id; ?>"><?php echo $municipal->first_name.' '.$municipal->last_name; ?></option>
                                        <?php endif; ?>
                                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        <?php endfor; ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: And your question is...

Comment: I spent days trying to making that output and just failed :D i thought i could get some help here

Comment: Show us what you have attempted. The code.

Comment: Ok i need made an edit and added my code

Comment: By the way there was no need for this minus 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make use of [`array_shift()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php) function and a simple `for` loop to implement your logic, like this:

```
$myArray = array('a','c');

for($i = 0; $i < 4; ++$i){
    $flag = false;
    ?>
    <select id="id" name="id" class="form-control">
        <option value="">No selection</option>
        <option value="a" <?php if(!$flag && in_array('a', $myArray)){ echo "selected='selected'"; $flag = true; } ?>>a</option>
        <option value="b" <?php if(!$flag && in_array('b', $myArray)){ echo "selected='selected'"; $flag = true; } ?>>b</option>
        <option value="c" <?php if(!$flag && in_array('c', $myArray)){ echo "selected='selected'"; $flag = true; } ?>>c</option>
        <option value="d" <?php if(!$flag && in_array('d', $myArray)){ echo "selected='selected'"; $flag = true; } ?>>d</option>
    </select>
    <?php
    array_shift($myArray);
}
```

**Note:** Take care of `id` and `name` attributes, it should be unique for every element.

Comment: @YasserMoussa Glad I could help you. *Cheers! :-)*

Answer (score 0):

Here's some sample code:

```
$myArray = array('a','b','c','d');
$selected_values = array('a','c');
$number_of_selects = 4;

for ($i = 0; $i < $number_of_selects; $i++) {
    $sel_val = !empty($selected_values[$i])? $selected_values[$i] : false;?>
<select>
<?php
    foreach ($myArray as $v) {?>
        <option value="<?=$v?>" <?=$v===$sel_val? 'selected' : ''?>><?=$v?><option>
<?php
    }?>
</select>
<?php
}
```